# passing null to CTE to get all records as a default?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the CTE as a UDF and am trying to get it to take a default value of nothing in which case the result returned should be everything.

I want to call it as a default like this:

```
select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername
```

my UDF/ CTE is:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername]   
(      
  @AMRSNTID varchar(100) = null  
)    
RETURNS TABLE    
AS    
RETURN    
(    
  WITH yourcte AS    
  (    
    SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerAMRSNTID, ManagerID, AMRSNTID, FullName, 0 as depth--, Name    
    FROM Employees    
    WHERE AMRSNTID = @AMRSNTID
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerAMRSNTID, e.ManagerID, e.AMRSNTID, e.FullName, y.depth+1 as depth--, e.Name    
    FROM Employees e    
    JOIN yourcte y ON e.ManagerAMRSNTID = y.AMRSNTID
  )    
SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, AMRSNTID, FullName, depth--, Name    
FROM yourcte    
)
```

How can I get it to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the UDF

```
WHERE AMRSNTID = ISNULL(@AMRSNTID, AMRSNTID)
```

And call it thus

```
select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername(DEFAULT)
--or
select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername(NULL)
```

Edit: without seeing your data or how the hierarchy looks, you need to add the an OPTION clause
If it runs forever, you have a circular link somewhere

```
select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername(DEFAULT) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Note: you can't have the OPTION inside the UDF

Edit2: my mistake sorry. You need to start at employees who have no manager (i.e. start at the top)

Something like

```
WHERE
    (@AMRSNTID IS NOT NULL AND AMRSNTID = @AMRSNTID)
    OR
    (@AMRSNTID IS NULL AND ManagerAMRSNTID IS NULL)
```

Comment: i get this error: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: it seems to run forever. the self-referencing table Employees has 1000 records that create a tree of 1000 nodes. the result of adding the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) resulted in 500,000 records when i stopped it after 25 seconds.

Comment: @kacalapy: you have a recursion then. EmpA to EmpB to EmpC to EmpA etc

Comment: when i run select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername('jferlisi') this is the top most record the maximum depth is 6 for a certain manager that has a deep (6 level deep) tree under them... and there are 327 records. this constitutes a full tree resultset of the data table.

Comment: i tried the 2 conditions but get no data abck using : select * from fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername (null). if i use a param it shows good data.

Comment: @kacalapy: well, you need to have a think about what you need to change to find the top manager entry point when @AMRSNTID is null.

Comment: @gbn; i got it with the code below. it was a logical puzzle that stumped us both...

Answer (score 0):

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeHierarchyByUsername]  
(      
  @AMRSNTID varchar(100) = null  
)    
RETURNS TABLE    
AS    
RETURN    
(    
  WITH yourcte AS    
  (    
    SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerAMRSNTID, ManagerID, AMRSNTID, FullName, 0 as depth--, Name    
    FROM Employees    
    WHERE (AMRSNTID = @AMRSNTID) or (@AMRSNTID is null and managerID is null)
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerAMRSNTID, e.ManagerID, e.AMRSNTID, e.FullName, y.depth+1 as depth--, e.Name    
    FROM Employees e    
    JOIN yourcte y ON e.ManagerAMRSNTID = y.AMRSNTID
  )    

SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerID, AMRSNTID, FullName, depth--, Name    
FROM yourcte    
)
```